# Entity Framework 4.1 and the Generic IRepository<T> Pattern and Windsor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, entity-framework-4.1

A follow up question to [Entity Framework RC1 DbContext query issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333847/entity-framework-rc1-dbcontext-query-issue)

I am able to inject my DbContext using

```
    Component.For<IEFDataContextProvider>().ImplementedBy<EFDataContextProvider>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
        .DynamicParameters((k, d) => d["context"] = new PLSS.Models.PlssContext())
```

and this is working great. However this only works if my context initializer does not need to drop the database.

```
    DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PlssContext>
```

creates the error

> Cannot drop database "PLSS.Models.PlssContext" because it is currently in use.

I assume that means that this is in use from the windsor container.  Does this have to do with the LifeStyle being PerWebRequest?  I have also tried Transient with the same issue.

Also how would I use the xml container representation to create the components.  I'd rather have it in my windsor.config so I can change it if necessary.

I thought this would be equivalent to what I have above using the fluent api but i get a strange error i will post below.

```
  <component
  id="IEFDataContextProvider"
  service="AGRC.Common.Repositories.IEFDataContextProvider, AGRC.Common"
  type="AGRC.Common.Repositories.EFDataContextProvider, AGRC.Common"
  lifestyle="PerWebRequest">
  <parameters>
    <context>
      ${PlssContext}
    </context>
  </parameters>
</component>

<component
  id="PlssContext"
  type="PLSS.Models.PlssContext, PLSS.Models"
  lifestyle="transient">
</component>
```

> Method 'GetControllerSessionBehavior' in type 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcDynamicSessionControllerFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Not sure whats up with that but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have been a classic case of [image]

Think I had an active connection in my server explorer.

Comment: also had mvc futures in the project. removed that. then had the wrong assembly in my xml config.  geeze.

Answer (score 0):

You have a version of the assembly that's compiled against MVC2 and you're using MVC3

Comment: that i was able to figure out from a cool nuget package called MvcDiagnostics.  Since you're the windsor guru, can you tell me about the first question? But what difference does the xml and the fluent way matter when doing this since i only get that error when doing it the xml way?  It's a mvc futures dll also btw.

Comment: Try specifying full assembly name in XML including version

Comment: how about the "currently in use" issue? with the container and the drop and recreate db?